# Swagger UI has wrong base path

Tags: rest, swagger-ui

I am using the grape-swagger gem and the standalone installation of [SwaggerUI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui). My API documentation is situated at http://example.com/api/v1/docs/. SwaggerUI discovers all resources, but sends all requests to http://example.com/v1/foo (missing 'api/' from the URL). Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

For documentation if somebody experiences the same problem: There is a paramater for the grape-swagger method `add_swagger_documentation` called `base_path`. In my case, I had to specify

```
base_path: '/api'
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem using maven with spring-boot ans swagger-ui 2.4.0.
Probable incompatibilities with other packages like thymeleaf regarding resources urls might be responsible for the problem.

As a workaround, I could overcome the broken links by remapping the url like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomResourceMapping extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  { 
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController(
        "/configuration/ui", 
        "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui");
        registry.addRedirectViewController(
        "/configuration/security", 
        "/swagger-resources/configuration/security");
    }
}
```